# Using a return constexpr pair for template instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, constexpr

I am trying to use data from a `std::pair` that is returned by a `constexpr` free function. The first element determines the size of a `std::array` while the second element is stored in the array.

```c++
using DataBundle = std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int>>;

constexpr DataBundle get_data()
{
    // other work carried out here
    return std::make_pair(1, std::make_pair(2, 3));
}

struct x
{
    template<int size>
    using OtherData = std::array<std::pair<int, int>, size>;

    static constexpr OtherData<get_data().first> foo { get_data().second };
};
```

The above code isn't as efficient as it could be, as `get_data()` is called twice in the instantiation of `foo`. One solution could be to store the returned data as a member of the struct `x`, as shown below.

```c++
// previous code remains the same

struct x
{
    template<int size>
    using OtherData = std::array<std::pair<int, int>, size>;

    static constexpr DataBundle foo_bundle = get_data(); 
    static constexpr OtherData<foo_bundle.first> foo { foo_bundle.second };
};
```

Although this solution doesn't seem to take full advantage of the template mechanism. So my question is if there is a better approach to this that gets the best out of each of the above samples?

Comment: What do you mean, "full advantage of the template mechanism"? What's wrong with the second example?

Comment: _isn't as efficient_ How do you measure performance at compile time? For all you know, the compiler called it just once. Especially since it's const_expr. The whole point is for the compiler to compute it just once.

Comment: Good point, I didn't consider the possibility of `get_data` only being called once. And what I meant by "full advantage of the template mechanism" is by calling `get_data` inline to the template instantiation. But if it is potentially calling `get_data` a single time then I shouldn't worry about referencing the function call within multiple places of the instantiation.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed constexpr function might be computed several times (whereas template class should be instantiated only once), for trivial case as your, first snippet would be fine.

I would create dedicated function/lambda to create `foo` though:

```
struct x
{
    template<int size>
    using OtherData = std::array<std::pair<int, int>, size>;

    static constexpr auto foo = []() {
        constexpr DataBundle foo_bundle = get_data(); 

        return OtherData<foo_bundle.first>{foo_bundle.second};
    } ();
};
```